# ExtJs grid not refreshing after adding a new record

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using ExtJS API for CRUD operations in grid. All of my code works fine except one small thing. When I add a record first time(when the page is loaded) the new record is not shown on the grid but it is added in the database. When I refreshes the page and insert a record it is shown as soon as it is added. This is a very strange behavior and I don't even have a clue what's going on here. Here is the code I am using to insert a record:

```
insertUser: function (button) {
        var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#userlist');
        var win = button.up('window');
        form = win.down('form');
        record = form.getRecord();
        values = form.getValues();
        this.getUsersStore().add(values);
        this.getUsersStore().reload();//tried this.getUsersStore().load(); also    
        win.close();
    }
```

Can any one point out what's wrong going on here? Thanks.

Comment: try `grid.getView().refresh();`?

Comment: Thanks 99 Red Balloons. I just removed the line record = form.getRecord(); and everything worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

When adding a data to store it needs to be in the format of the store record.

For example

```
this.getUsersStore().add({username:'Sample User', userid: 210, userphone: '999-999-9000'});
```

In your code it seems that you are directly passing the values.

If you add the record correctly store does't need to do reload() or refreshed, if you reload() the store gets refreshed and the data you added will not be present.